# Regex Non-Greedy match acts greedily with whitespace

Tags: regex

I have a blob of text like:

```
6.9 fdafsaf

dfasfsdafasdf
asdfsdaf.
asdfasfsa

6.9.1 asdfasdffsdaasdfdfasasdf

adfdafsdfasdfassdfa.
asdfasdf.asdf.
 
6.10.1 header
 
adfsfdasfadfasd.
asdfasdfsa.asdf.
asdfasdf.
 
 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
....
</xs:schema>
```

I want to extract 2 things:

1. The closest header

```
6.10.1 header
```

2. The XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
....
</xs:schema>
```

So I match the header:

```
(\d+\.\d+\.\d+.*)
```

Then a lazy match of text:

```
[\s\S]*?
```

Then the XML:

```
(<\?xml[\s\S]*?<\/xs:schema>)
```

However, the match I get includes the previous header too!

(Full Match)

```
6.9.1 asdfasdffsdaasdfdfasasdf

adfdafsdfasdfassdfa

6.10.1 header

adfsfdasfadfasd


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
....
</xs:schema>
```

Clearly, my lazy quantifier between the header and xml is incorrect. I really want to specify the first match where that space between the two doesn't include any header matches.

How do I do this?

Full expression:

```
(\d+\.\d+\.\d+.*)[\s\S]*?(<\?xml[\s\S]*?<\/xs:schema>)
```

Comment: What differentiates `6.9.1 asdfasdffsdaasdfdfasasdf` from `6.10.1 header` as being a header.  They both follow a `\d+.\d+.\d+` pattern

Comment: @duncan, Nothing they are both headers. I only want the *closest* header, where that is defined as the header where no further headers are matched before the XML. Does that make sense or do you need more clarification?

Comment: I think the `.*` at the end of `(\d+\.\d+\.\d+.*)`  will cause it to match everything up until where it matches `(<\?xml[\s\S]*?<\/xs:schema>)`

Comment: @duncan, That is correct, The `.*` will match up till the end of that line (So it will be the full header `6.9.1 asdfasdffsdaasdfdfasasdf`). The `.` specifier doesn't allow newlines though, so the quantifier will end there. I really want an expression that will match `[\s\S]*?` but not allow any `(\d+\.\d+\.\d+.*)` header matches in it. This would force it to match `6.10.1 header` instead of `6.9.1 asdfasdffsdaasdfdfasasdf`.

Comment: You just need a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That looks correct, thanks! If you want to post an answer, I will accept it, otherwise I can figure it out on my own from there.